# Is cross-posting the same question to multiple sites not allowed when it is on-topic everywhere?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I recently asked this question [Why Newton wanted lines to be generated by continued motion of points rather than by apposition of parts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403043/why-newton-wanted-lines-to-be-generated-by-continued-motion-of-points-rather-tha?noredirect=1#comment2861882_1403043)  in MSE. I did get response on the day of my submission of question, but I was not satisfied. So, I thought of posting the same in PSE, as I thought it would also be on topic there also. While I was discussing there, someone said me that, the question best suits to HSM, so I posted the same question there also.

Arthur Fischer commented:

> Don't cross-post the same questions to multiple sites.

Is it not allowed to cross-post when it is on-topic everywhere? If it is not allowed, I don't understand why, each group, whether mathematicians, physicists, historians, or any other group will have different things to say about the same question, then I don't think it to be a bad idea to cross-post. I felt bad from Fischer's response :(

I don't understand whether the question was not on-topic in MSE, as it was migrated to HSM. I wanted to discuss little more, particularly in MSE, which I can't do now, as it is migrated.

**The purpose of me wasting my time here is, I don't want the same thing to happen for other questions, which will get different anwers/views from different sites.**

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posting is generally frowned upon.  However, if you *do* cross-post, make sure that each site has a link to all the cross-posted copies so that effort is not duplicated.

Comment: @robjohn: I did also provide links to all other copies,,, :(

Comment: This is related to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9337). You might also browse the questions tagged [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: [See also this comparison to falafel](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo).

Comment: Another issue I've seen is that there are often users who are active on different sites that are interconnected. For example, several of the most active users on HSM are also active on Mathematics and/or Math Overflow and/or Physics (and of course vice versa - to a tiny extent). There's a fair amount of crossover, so by asking on one site, you're not cutting yourself off from significant populations of potential answerers.

Answer (score 22):

Cross-posting *the same* question to multiple sites is generally frowned upon *across the network*; see [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). [Jeff Atwood's own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073) to that question is perhaps interesting to read as he is one of the founders of this network. Here is a partial quote.

> There are some questions which fall into grey areas between sites, and I think it's OK to **ask and delete, then re-ask** if you feel you have asked on the wrong site.
>
> But as a general rule, do not cross-post questions, please. Pick a site and go with it.

Jeff also spoke about this in [this meta.physics answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/896), where he added

> It is also ok to ask *two different versions* of a question but you MUST tailor it to the audience on that site.

It is important to keep in mind that math.se is only one part of this network. While the issue of cross-posting will likely have to be dealt with in a more robust manner at some point (it is certainly not even in the famed "6-8 week" time-frame yet), for the time being most sites *strongly discourage* cross-posting the same question.